# Regex: match one pattern and exclude another pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have a regular expression that matches the phone numbers:

```
import re
phones = re.findall(r'[+(]?[0-9][0-9 \-()]{8,}[0-9]', text)
```

It shows good accuracy in a large raw text dataset.

But sometimes it matches unwanted results (ranges of years and random IDs).

Ranges of years:

```
'2012 - 2017'
'(2011 - 2013'
'1999                                                   02224'
'2019     2010-2015'
'2018-2018 (5'
'2004 -2009'
'1) 2005-2006'
'2011            2020'
```

Random ids:

```
'5                    5                    5                 5'
'100032479008252'
'100006711277302'
```

I have ideas on how to solve these problems.

1. Limit the total number of digits to 12 digits.
2. Limit the total number of characters to 16 characters.
3. Remove the ranges of years (`19**|20** - 19**|20**`).

But I do not know how to implement these ideas and make them as exceptions in my regular expression.

Some examples that a regular expression should catch are presented below:

```
380-956-425979
+38(097)877-43-88
+38(050) 284-24-20
(097) 261-60-52
380-956-425979
(068)1850063
0975533222
```

Comment: Try precising the pattern rather than adding exclusions. E.g. `\+?(?:\([0-9]{1,4}\)|\b[0-9]{1,4}|\b)[0-9](?:[ -]?[0-9]){8}(?!\d)` or `\+?(?:\([0-9]{1,3}\)|\b[0-9]{1,3}|\b)[0-9](?:[ -]?[0-9]){9}(?!\d)`. In most cases, it will be safer to post-process matches rather than trying to cram everything into a single pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, these regular expressions, unlike the previous expression, do not catch such examples: 
'380-936-745979'
'+38(093)797-43-82'
'+38(098) 278-33-20'
'(095) 356-44-52'
'380-986-898979'
'(069)1960063'

Comment: Not fully test it yet:`text = "+(123) 1234-1234"`
`phones = re.findall(r'\+?(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3}) ?\d{4}\-?\d{4}', text)`

Comment: @Frank, unfortunately, it doesn't catch any example in my comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you write different patterns for different phone strucutres. I'm not so sure about your phone number structures, but this matches your example:

```
import re
test = '''380-956-425979
+38(097)877-43-88
+38(050) 284-24-20
(097) 261-60-52
380-956-425979
(068)1850063
0975533222'''
solution = test.split("\n")

p1 = "\+?\d{3}\-\d{3}\-\d{6}"
p2 = "\+?(?:\d{2})?\(\d{3}\) ?\d{3}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}"
p3 = "\+?\d{3}\-\d{3}\-\d{6}"
p4 = "\+?(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})\d{7}"

result = re.findall(f'{p1}|{p2}|{p3}|{p4}', test)
print(solution)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in python directly:

```
if regex.match("condition", "teststring") and not regex.match("not-condition", "teststring"):
   print("Match!")
```